# Draw 3D model of more than one curve in matlab with vectors

Tags: matlab

I'm doing a project that involves making a 3D model of the cornea in matlab. I have 6 plot3 in the same graph to draw one cornea

[image]

but now i want a surface plot.

[image]

Don't mind the curve orientation.
Note that all the plot3 have x, y and z that are vectors

Thanks in advance

Comment: What attempts you made? This involves _interpolation_.

Comment: I tried to use the scatter3 function but it gives me something like the first image but the lines are color coded by depth

Comment: Scatter is used to plot...attach your data...

Comment: [link] (https://1drv.ms/f/s!AuTa2aNlfXCgjQtJ8XDZSKhhQqA7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would use the Surf command [doku surf](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html). It is used to display [x,y,z] data. Since you have not have as many touples of data (just 6) you will have to interpolate all the other values. Therefore I would use the scattered interpolant function [doku scattered interpolant](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant.html).

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Take care all this is pseudocode!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
F = scatteredInterpolant(x_existing,y_existing,z_existing);
```

generates a scattered interpolant object. You do already feed your already existing data in there. Afterwards you generate the points at which you want to interpolate:

```
%generates samples from -4 t0 4 in 0.05 steps
   [x_sample,y_sample] = meshgrid(-4:0.05:4,-4:0.05:4);
```

Now you calculate the fitted z values using the scattered interpolant obj

```
z_interpolated=F(x_sample,y_sample) %interpolates
surf(x_sample,y_sample,z_interpolated) %plots with surf between -4 and 4
```

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!From here working code!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
   %serialiasation of data (special for this usecase)
x_data=[h0(30:632,6);(a30(28:408,3))+0.527;(a60(276:632,3));(a90(26:575,3))+3.417;(a120(188:586,3))-0.6625;(a150(16:380,3))+1.173];
y_data=[(h0(30:632,5));((a30(28:408,2))-0.9128);(a60(276:632,2));(a90(26:575,2));(a120(188:586,2))-0.3825;((a150(16:380,2))+2.032)];
z_data=[yA0;yA30+0.162;yA60;yA90+0.837;yA120+0.135;yA150+0.135];

% cleaning the data of nan values
x_data=x_data(~isnan(z_data));
y_data=y_data(~isnan(z_data));
z_data=z_data(~isnan(z_data));%random for the looks


%interpolating
F=scatteredInterpolant(x_data,y_data,z_data);
%read yourself what this does
F.Method = 'natural';
F.ExtrapolationMethod = 'none';

%choosing sample points
[x_sample,y_sample] = meshgrid(-6:0.05:6,-6:0.05:6);

%interpolation
z_interpolated=F(x_sample,y_sample);
%plot
surf(x_sample,y_sample,z_interpolated)
```

I hope I was able to help you. If you try it and it works it would be very nice of you to post the working code here so that in the future here stands a working solution.

Comment: gives me an error like this "z_interpolated =

     []

Error using surf (line 71)
Data dimensions must agree.

Error in horizontal (line 219)
surf(x_sample,y_sample,z_interpolated) %plots with surf between -4 and 4 "

Comment: I edited my answer. It should work now even though it needs some more sample points to look more nice.

Comment: And here is the full code:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhG7lih1HTfeaMPRQyCa75onMtA

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works! I used mesh instead of surf so the surface would be more colourful  like the one in the second image in my original question. The only thing is that i would like it to look more round and pretty like the second image any suggestions?

Comment: I think you need more  samples. Maybe look at your polyfit . They are throwing some errors.